# Why abstract method fillOval() can be directly used?

Tags: java

I read a GUI program like this:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class TestPaint{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new PaintFrame().launchFrame();
    }
}

class PaintFrame extends Frame{

    public void launchFrame(){
        setBounds(200,200,640,480);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Color c = g.getColor();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(50,50,50,50);
        g.fillRect(80,80,40,40);
        g.setColor(c);
    }

}
```

This is a program that can run in memory, here are the results,
[Sorry I do not have enough reputation to post images, but it can run]

when I read APIfile, I found fillOval() method is defined in Graphics class like this :

```
public abstract void fillOval(int x,
                              int y,
                              int width,
                              int height)
```

Why can I directly use abstract fillOval() in the program? Furthermore, where can I find the concrete implements of fillOval() at this program?

Answer (score 2):

In order for any abstract class to be instantiated there **must** be a concrete implementation somewhere. It is that implementation that is invoked.

Just as with an interface, the contract is all that is specified.

Thus, you can safely invoke the method (because the contract must be honored by any implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Since abstract methods cannot be in a non abstract class `Graphics` class should be abstract. You cannot create instance of an abstract class and neither `fillOval()` method is static. So there is no way to call the method.

Now coming to the facts. Abstract methods in abstract class should be implemented by the 1st concrete class that extends the abstract class. So you have to create a non abstract class that `extends Graphics` and provide implementation of `fillOval()` in it. Then create and instance of it in your program and call it.

Comment: There should never be a need to extending from `Graphics` in order to provide an implementation - unless your are seriously considering writing an implementation for a different graphics driver or something, but then you'd need to re-implement the entire core AWT library to support it...just saying ;)

Comment: In that case I am sure there is a default implementation already provided in AWT library :) @ZHI do check and use it,

Comment: Please check my whole program, I provide it at question. My question now is where can I find the concrete implemention of fillOval()?

Comment: @ZHI You'd have to go to the source of the JVM, look it up, it's functionality will be dependent on the platform build of the JVM

Answer (score 0):

The `Graphics` object that gets passed to that method is actually a subclass of that class (since any object that extends from a `SomeClass` "is-a" `SomeClass`, and that concrete subclass implements the logic of the `fillOval` method.

For example:

```
abstract class A {
    abstract void doStuff();
}

class B extends A {
    void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("B::doStuff()");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A obj = new B();
        obj.doStuff(); // prints B::doStuff()
    }
}
```

If you want to see the actual type of the object, you can use `g.getClass().getCanonicalName()` which in this case evaluates to `sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D`. The source code can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java#SunGraphics2D.fillOval%28int%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29).

Comment: *"which in this case evaluates to sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D"* - Yes and no, it evaluates to that on your implementation of the JVM ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got to know there is polymorphism to call fillOval() function, the Graphics g which passed into the function is a sub-class reference.